# Use perl to do multi-line replacement

Tags: regex, sed, perl, find-and-replace

I have to do some replacements in many `*.c` files. I want to do the replacement like this:
original: `printf("This is a string! %d %d\n", 1, 2);`
result: `print_record("This is a string! %d %d", 1, 2);`
That is, replace the "`printf`" with "`print_record`", and remove the trailing "`\n`".
At first, I use `sed` to do this task. However, maybe there are some cases like this:

```
printf("This is a multiple string, that is very long"
 " and be separated into multiple lines. %d %d\n", 1, 2);
```

In this case, I can't use `sed` to remove the "`\n`" easily. I heard that `perl` can do this work well. But I am fresh to `perl`. So can anyone help me? How to accomplish this with `perl`?
Thanks very much!

Comment: You might be interested in [`spatch`](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/sp.php) ([LWN](https://lwn.net/Articles/315686/)).

Comment: @grawity Thanks! I have look through the `spatch`. It is a very convenient tool. However, I think it can't accomplish the task that checks if there is a trailing "`\n`" in the `fmt` string parameter and remove it if there is. In my opinion, `spatch` can deal with a whole parameter, but not part of it. What do you think so? Thanks very much for introducing me to this interesting tool.

Comment: Commenting on the close votes: there is some interest to this question (I believe) as it requires a moderate amount of parsing. Maybe this question might be migrated to StackOverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not trivial. It requires some parsing to take care of balanced delimiters, quoting, and the C rule that adjacent string literals be joined into a single one. Fortunately, the Perl module [Text::Balanced](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Balanced) handles a lot of this (Text::Balanced is available in the Perl 'standard' library). The following script should do more or less what you want. It takes one command-line argument and outputs on standard output. You'll have to wrap it inside a shell script. I used the following wrapper to test it:

```
#/bin/bash
find in/ -name '*.c' -exec sh -c 'in="$1"; out="out/${1#in/}"; perl script.pl "$in" > "$out"' _ {} \;
colordiff -ru expected/ out/
```

And here's the Perl script. I wrote some comments, but feel free to ask if you need more explanation.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp 'read_file';
use Text::Balanced 'extract_bracketed', 'extract_delimited';

my $text = read_file(shift);

my $last = 0;
while ($text =~ /(          # store all matched text in $1
                  \bprintf  # start of literal word 'printf'
                  (\s*)     # optional whitespace, stored in $2
                  (?=\()    # lookahead for literal opening parenthesis
                 )/gx) {
    # after a successful match,
    #   1. pos($text) is on the character right behind the match (opening parenthesis)
    #   2. $1 contains the matched text (whole word 'printf' followed by optional
    #      whitespace, but not the opening parenthesis)
    #   3. $2 contains the (optional) whitespace

    # output up to, but not including, 'printf'
    print substr($text, $last, pos($text) - $last - length($1));
    print "print_record$2(";

    # extract and process argument
    my ($argument) = extract_bracketed($text, '()');
    process_argument($argument);

    # save current position
    $last = pos($text);
}

# output remainder of text
print substr($text, $last);

# process_argument() properly handles the situation of a format string
# consisting of adjacent string literals
sub process_argument {
    my $argument = shift;

    # skip opening parenthesis retained by extract_bracketed()
    $argument =~ /^\(/g;

    # scan for quoted strings
    my $saved;
    my $last = 0;
    while (1) {
        # extract quoted string
        my ($string, undef, $whitespace) = extract_delimited($argument, '"');
        last if !$string;       # quit if not found

        # as we still have strings remaining, the saved one wasn't the last and should
        # be output verbatim
        print $saved if $saved;
        $saved = $whitespace . $string;
        $last = pos($argument);
    }
    if ($saved) {
        $saved =~ s/\\n"$/"/;   # chop newline character sequence off last string
        print $saved;
    }

    # output remainder of argument
    print substr($argument, $last);
}
```